# Copy Maven resources from folder to root

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have the following structure in resources folder in Maven project:

```
src\main\resources\base\spring\menu1.config
src\main\resources\base\spring\menu2.config
....
src\main\resources\base\spring\menu<N>.config
```

When the JAR is packaged, I want to copy this config to the root of the jar and don't want to maintain the folder structure in the packaged JAR.
I was trying with *maven-resources-plugin* but could not pull this off. Please guide me how to do that.

Also, another question is, there are some properties file which differs for different environment i.e. `Local/prod/dev` will have diff version of these property files. So, the structure looks like this:

```
src\main\resource\props\local\db.properties
src\main\resource\props\dev\db.properties
src\main\resource\props\prod\db.properties
```

I want to take any of these files according to the environment. Meaning, when buidling in `dev`, I want to take it from dev folder and when in `prod`, I want to take from `prod` folder accordingly.
Please guide me how to this.

Comment: you could try to use this: https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin if it helps ?

Answer (score 0):

In the build section of your pom have the following.

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/${environment}/base/spring</directory>
            <targetPath>${basedir}/target/classes</targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

Then pass in the ${environment} from the command:

```
mvn clean install -Denviroment=dev
```